# How to add cell from one collectionView to another

Tags: ios, swift, collectionview

I have got a collection view with data from API.

There is a button in Cell which should add cell to another collectionView called Favorites

how can i move that

i have tried to add extra option to my model to find favorites every element marked but it doesn't work

```
// MARK: - Movie
struct Movie: Codable {
    let resultCount: Int?
    let favorite: Bool?
    let results: [Results]?
}

// MARK: - Result
struct Results: Codable {
    let wrapperType: WrapperType?
    let kind: Kind?
    let collectionID, trackID: Int?
    let artistName, collectionName, trackName, collectionCensoredName: String?
    let trackCensoredName: String?
    let collectionArtistID: Int?
    let collectionArtistViewURL, collectionViewURL, trackViewURL: String?
    let previewURL: String?
    let artworkUrl30, artworkUrl60, artworkUrl100: String?
    let collectionPrice, trackPrice, trackRentalPrice, collectionHDPrice: Double?
    let trackHDPrice, trackHDRentalPrice: Double?
    let releaseDate: String?
    let collectionExplicitness, trackExplicitness: Explicitness?
    let discCount, discNumber, trackCount, trackNumber: Int?
    let trackTimeMillis: Int?
    let country: Country?
    let currency: Currency?
    let primaryGenreName: PrimaryGenreName?
    let contentAdvisoryRating: ContentAdvisoryRating?
    let longDescription: String?
    let hasITunesExtras: Bool?
    let shortDescription: String?
    let artistID: Int?
    let artistViewURL: String?
```

}

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {


let networkService = NetworkService()
var movie: Movie? = nil

let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero,
                               collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
        setupCollectionView()
    
    let url = "https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=movie"
    networkService.request(URL: url) { [self] (result) in
        switch result {
        case .success(let movie):
            self.movie = movie
            collectionView.reloadData()
        case .failure(let error):
            print("error", error)
        }
    }
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    collectionView.frame = view.bounds
    
    
    }
    




        
       
func setupCollectionView() {
    collectionView.register(CustomCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "identifier")
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.delegate = self
    view.addSubview(collectionView)
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 10    }
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 1    }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: view.frame.size.width/3 - 4, height: view.frame.size.width/2)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return (movie?.results?.count) ?? 0
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "identifier", for: indexPath) as! CustomCollectionViewCell
    cell.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 15
    cell.imageView.downloaded(from: (movie?.results![indexPath.row].artworkUrl100)!)
    return cell
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let DetailsVC = DetailsViewController()
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(DetailsVC, animated: true)
    DetailsVC.imageView.downloaded(from: (movie?.results![indexPath.row].artworkUrl100)!)
    DetailsVC.yearLabel.text = " Год выпуска: \(movie?.results![indexPath.row].releaseDate ?? "")"
    DetailsVC.nameLabel.text = (movie?.results![indexPath.row].trackName)
    DetailsVC.genreLabel.text = (movie?.results![indexPath.row].primaryGenreName?.rawValue)
    DetailsVC.producerLabel.text = (movie?.results![indexPath.row].artistName)
    DetailsVC.descritionLabel.text = (movie?.results![indexPath.row].longDescription)
}
```

}

```
class NetworkService {


func request(URL url:String, completion: @escaping (Result<Movie, Error>) -> Void) {
    guard let url = URL(string: url) else { return }
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data, response, error) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if let error = error {
                print("Some error")
                completion(.failure(error))
                return
            }
            guard let data = data else { return }
            do {
                let movies = try
                JSONDecoder().decode(Movie.self, from: data)
                completion(.success(movies))
            } catch let JsonError{
                print("Failed to decode JSON", JsonError)
                completion(.failure(JsonError  ))
        
            }
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

}

class CustomCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

```
let imageView: UIImageView = {
    let iv = UIImageView()
    iv.clipsToBounds = true
    iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    return iv
}()
let likeButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton()
    button.setImage(UIImage(named: "heart"), for: .normal)
    return button
}()
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    //button
    self.contentView.addSubview(likeButton)
    likeButton.layer.zPosition = 1
    likeButton.snp.makeConstraints{ make in
        make.right.equalTo(-10)
        make.top.equalTo(10)
        make.width.equalTo(30)
        make.height.equalTo(30)
    }
    likeButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(likeTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    //setup cell
    self.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 16
    self.contentView.clipsToBounds = true
    self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    self.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
    self.layer.shadowOffset = .zero
    self.layer.shadowRadius = 4.0
    self.layer.shouldRasterize = true
    self.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale
    self.layer.drawsAsynchronously = true
    self.layer.masksToBounds = false
    
    // Image setup
    self.contentView.addSubview(imageView)
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    imageView.snp.makeConstraints{ make in
        make.left.equalTo(0)
        make.right.equalTo(0)
        make.width.equalTo(contentView)
        make.height.equalTo(contentView)
    }
    
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
@objc func likeTapped() {
    if likeButton.tag == 0 {
        likeButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "redheart"), for: .normal)
        likeButton.tag = 1
        
    } else {
        likeButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "heart"), for: .normal)
        likeButton.tag = 0
    }
        
    }
```

}

is it possible just to add var favorite to my model to show data in another collectionView? The thing is the button which control these moves is placed in CustomCollectionViewCell

Comment: What is `NetworkService`? Is that a networking class from a 3rd party"

Comment: Is this it? https://swiftpackageindex.com/MFB-Technologies-Inc/NetworkService

Comment: Where is this favorite button you talk about? Where is the code that responds to the favorite button? Where is the second view controller that is supposed to add the favorited items? Where is the code that supports that behavior? You are really not describing your setup well at all. Having to ask 500 questions just to understand your problem is very frustrating. You need to review your question from the perspective of somebody who's never seen your app before and explain how everything works, and show the relevant code.

Comment: sorry i didnt expect fast reaction on my post 
i ve added my own network class
and custom cell

Comment: Ok, your like button toggles it's own tag between a 0 and a 1, and toggles the image between a heart and red heart image. You don't do **anything** else with the button tap. How could that possibly pass your list of favorited items to a separate collection view controller? Where is the separate collection view controller? There are more open questions than answers.

Comment: You need to think in terms of a MODEL - an object that holds the information you are displaying in your collection view controller(s). When the user taps a favorite button, you need that button to pass a message to your view controller, and your view controller needs to modify your model to reflect that the user has favorited/unfavorited an item. You then need to tell your current collection view controller to reload the changed cell, and also notify your favorites view controller about the change in favorited items.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reframe the question.

You don't "add cells to another collection view". You update the model the other collection view displays.

You need to figure out how your app's data model is set up. One possibility is to add an "is favorite" flag to the entries in your model, and have your favorites view controller filter the model to show those entries that are marked as favorites. When the user clicks a button in the other view controller, you'd update your model to mark that entry as a favorite, and then send a notification of some sort to the other view controller that the model had changed. (It could be a broadcast "model has changed" notification, or you could craft a more targeted "item xyz added to favorites" message).

I don't have a code to give you because it would be specific to your app.

Comment: I appreciate your help !
i added my code to  the question. As you can see i added a flag Favorite to my model
could you please advice me how can i move data to another collectionView using this Flag
Thank you!